# Jquery find child dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I'm running into a problem at finding my DropdownList control inside a GridViewChild that is under another GridViewChild , how can I find this DropdownList ? Does anyone have an idea?

The ID of the DropDownList is "DDLCourseMother".

Thank you very much in advance.

**Mark-up Language:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="ParentGvMother" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="list" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="ParentGvMother_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                             
                            <img alt="" src="Images/plusGrid16x16.png"/>
                            <%--Child Block GridView Blocks--%>
                            
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlChildBlocks" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                            <asp:GridView ID="GvChildBlock" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="list" DataKeyNames="BlockID" EmptyDataText="Não existem ações filhas." OnRowDataBound="GvChildBlock_RowDataBound">
                                
                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="20px"/>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                         <img alt="" src="Images/plusGrid16x16.png"/>
                                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlInBlocks" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                                <%--GridViewInsideBlocks--%>
                                                <asp:GridView ID="GvInBlocks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="list" OnRowDataBound="GvInBlocks_RowDataBound">
                                                    
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Curso">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                         <asp:Label ID="lblChildBlockCourse" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseID") %>' Visible = "false" />
                                                         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDLCourseMother"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>

                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                    </ItemTemplate>    
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function () {
            $("[id*=DDLCourseMother]").select2();
        });
```

**Raw HTML Code:**

```
<select name="ParentGvMother$ctl02$GvChildBlock$ctl02$GvInBlocks$ctl02$DDLCourseMother" id="ParentGvMother_ctl02_GvChildBlock_ctl02_GvInBlocks_ctl02_DDLCourseMother" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="ParentGvMother_ctl02_GvChildBlock_ctl02_GvInBlocks_ctl02_DDLCourseMother">
                                                <option value="---------">---------</option>
                                                <option value="8221"> CompTIA Security+</option>
                                                <option value="7126"> Java Developer</option>
                                                <option value="4688"> HTML5</option>

                                            </select>
```

Comment: Off topic: wow, three letter prefixes (aka incorrectly-used-hungarian notation) - not seen that since the '90s.

Comment: jQuery is interacting with the resulting HTML in the browser, not the server-side code which produces that HTML.  What is that actual HTML?  Also, do you need to target just that specific `<select>` element, or do you want to target *all* `<select>` elements within that grid?

Comment: What does: `$(() => console.log($("[id*=DDLCourseMother]").length))` give you?

Comment: I want to target all select elements within that grid.

Comment: Your `pnlInBlocks` is `display:none` - are you sure it's not just because you can't see it?

Comment: Is it a bad practice ? DDLCourseMother?

Comment: I can see the control , but it's totally not working. I can't select any values.

Comment: meh - do what works for you (regarding `txt` `pnl` `ddl` etc)

Comment: If you remove your `.select2()` code, and see the original `<select>` does that have any values?

Comment: If I remove the .select2(), the dropdownlist would be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment on the question:

> I want to target all select elements within that grid.

Then don't bother trying to muck about with the WebForms controls and whatever HTML they produce and dynamically finding all of the unique `id`s therein and all that.

Simply wrap the whole grid in a `<div>` and target all `<select>` elements within that `<div>`.  For example:

```
<div id="your_grid">
  <asp:GridView ... />
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
$("#your_grid select").select2();
```

Comment: Tried it , but the dropdownlist is still not working.

Comment: @KiterCodes: Define "not working".  Please be specific about the problem you're observing and what debugging you do to gather more information about that problem.

Comment: So , here's what I did: In the server-side code I selected the values into that dropdown list(these values came from a DB) and that is working, but this is an edit page so the user should be able to select another values in that dropdownlist. If I try to open up the dropdown list to select another value the dropdownlist is not working. Although, If I remove the select2 function the dropdownlist is working.

Comment: @KiterCodes: So `select2` isn't including the options?  What is the actual HTML of the initial `<select>` element?  After the `select2` plugin is initialized on that element, how does that HTML change?  You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  It doesn't matter what you're doing server-side.  When the `select2` plugin is initialized on an HTML element, all it knows is that HTML element.  Use your browser's debugging to find information about that element.

Comment: In the select tag , I can see all the other options. Although , if I try to open up that dropdownlist I can't do it. But I checked in Chrome Dev Tools and the values are being displayed in HTML Code. The console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @KiterCodes: *"In the select tag , I can see all the other options."* - This is when you observe the raw HTML in the browser?  Can you *show* that HTML in your question?  *"Although , if I try to open up that dropdownlist I can't do it."* - Why can't you?  What specifically happens?  Does it display an empty list?  Is the element disabled?  Something else?  Be specific.  "It doesn't work" and "I can't do it" are not meaningful descriptions of a problem.

Comment: "In the select tag , I can see all the other options." - This is when you observe the raw HTML in the browser? - Yes it is.  "Although , if I try to open up that dropdownlist I can't do it." - It seems like it is somehow disabled.

Comment: Added the Raw HTML code in the question.